# Sending mail with SSL with Python 2.3

Tags: python, ssl, smtplib, python-2.3

I'm working with Python 2.3 and I need to send e-mails with SSL.

According to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP_SSL), SMTP_SSL was added in Python 2.6.

Is there a way to use SSL also in Python 2.3 (maybe with a third-party module)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can just use `starttls()`
just like:

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(mailhost)
smtp.starttls()
```

In SMTP_SSL doc you can find:

> SMTP_SSL should be used for situations where SSL is required from the
>   beginning of the connection and using starttls() is not appropriate.